# DMZ - Active Directory - (Philosophy)

Tags: networking, dns, firewall, dmz, domain-security

I have searched all over and found a lot of different answers to my question with no real direct Yes or No.

I made a very crude network diagram to explain what I would like to setup. 
I have setup a DMZ and an internal LAN. Eventually I will be setting up additional services that will be facing the internet. So I have read that having a RODC in the DMZ is a good idea, but I have also read that it is a terrible idea. In addition having a Child Domain reside in the DMZ is a good idea and also a bad idea.

I'm no stranger at all to how to set this servers and firewall rules up. What my problem is the philosophy behind the setups. I have a perimeter firewall and a back-end firewall all controlling access. Is the way I made the Network Diagram a good practice or a terrible practice ?

In addition I will like to setup a "one-way" trust between the Parent Domain and the Child Domain.

In addition I will only open up the firewall ports that I need to have the Primary DC communicate with the RODC. And nothing else

Some Network Info:

DMZ: 192.168.10.0/24 - Child Domain: DMZ.Contoso.com

LAN: 192.168.50.0/24 - Parent Domain: Contoso.com

Again, this type of question has been asked before but there are so many different opinions and ways of doing this type of setups that I want to know if mines is some what acceptable.

[image: Network Diagram]

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, I may lack experience in administering microsoft products.  Yet given my extensive background in UNIX & Linux Administration, I feel that it behooves you to consider the worst-case scenarios regarding the use of historically vulnerable software -- as Microsoft's own domain controller proves.

I feel much less hesitant deploying a BSD (Open, Free, or Net) using Samba to act as a domain controller -- especially the internet accessible, read only one in your diagram which sits on the DMZ.

Secondly, if I were designing the setup, I would place the internal LAN's DNS server and writable domain controller both on the DMZ, and setup a backend network with additional NICs and hubs/router for communication between themselves.  My reasoning: minimization of risk and mitigation of the potential damage in the event of a server compromise.  Real-world experience has taught me to expect as much, including the attempts at such, especially given your choice of operating systems.

No layer 3 or 4 firewall (darned near every one in existence...) in the world can protect you against attacks at layer 7 against valid and allowed ports and services.  Therefore, if it were me, I would put all servers on the DMZ, keep the writable domain controller off the public network, and with a backend private network for inter-server communications.  I would replace MS Windows with OpenBSD, running Samba and DJBDNS -- nothing else.  I would configure my routers to explicitly drop all inbound traffic except the conduits I explicitly define.  I would sanity-check my firewall configuration.  And if I had to run Windows on any of the servers, I would come up with a quick means of totally wiping the machines and restoring them to working, functional state with something like G4U.  I would also then have to investigate and install a means of being able to properly detect server compromises and attacks.  Better if the firewall automatically learned attacking IPs and made relevant DROP rules from such addresses -- yet not permanently, only for a day or two.

In your setup, a successful exploit can lead to using the compromised machines as stepping stones into your internal LAN.  Not exactly the kind of consequences that allow me to sleep tight at night, as a systems engineer and architect...

I recommend limiting potential damage, especially considering the historical record of non-trivial, remote exploitation of the software in your design.

Hope that helps!

F.

Comment: So you would place the writeable DC in a potentially more vulnerable zone? You probably should supply a diagram yourself because some of the other stuff does make it sound like you hopefully mean something different. Suggesting completely different products if you don't know the actual use case also doesn't really help.

Comment: Indeed, yes I would because I like to sleep at night, rather than having to get to the datacenter or colocation facility in the middle of the night.

Comment: @Francis, Thank you for your suggestions. It is not an option for me to switch out products and use UNIX and Linux based products. Not that I am afraid of them it is just to much of an infrastructure change. All products i'm sure are vulnerable at layer 7. My exposure as a SysAdmin has been to nearly 100% Microsoft products with a sprinkle of Linux(Red Hat) to be specific.

Comment: Indeed, yes I would because I like to sleep at night, rather than having to get to the datacenter or colocation facility in the middle of the night.  I base my opinion on real-world experience administering large server farms, a heterogeneous mix of BSDs, Linux, some traditional UNIX, and a few MS Windows servers.  A penetration tester would see the obvious inroads your unconventional use of the DMZ presents.  Theoretically, the DMZ should be purely isolated -- no way to get to internal LAN.  Something the likes of this might open your eyes: https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/40280/

Comment: Seth, I totally understand your reasoning and inability to switch OS.  No worries -- this makes all the more resolute my choice to put all servers on the DMZ, no other networks accessible except for a private, backend one on the DMZ for internal communication between the servers.  I would only expect to be attacked, and a successful compromise would not surprise me.  An isolated DMZ mitigates the damage, minimizes your risks.  Again, no firewall in the world will stop an attack at layer 7, and this becomes therefore a very useful front-door for anyone adept at intrusion.

Comment: Placing a writeable, productive DC in a DMZ would mean there is no reason to have a read only controller. Additionally you'd need to open your internal net towards your DMZ in order for ALL clients to communicate with servers in it rather than just one communication path from a relatively secure server. So if you manage to compromise that one server you can access all clients in the network. It would (as it is a writeable DC) indeed be access and not attack. A [DMZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)) by definition would not be a "private network for internal communication".

Comment: No, I mean isolated DMZ.  Internal access must come from the public internet, not an internal conduit between other networks on the firewall.  I want to leverage all of the outward facing protection my firewall and router configs provide, no sidestepping, and no vulnerable side channeling such conduits instantiate.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did a slight change in the design.
I did not extend the Active Directory into the DMZ as shown. Instead I made an entire new forest inside the DMZ and created a one-way trust between the internal forest and the DMZ forest. So even if my DMZ is compromised it will not matter since the data that is in the DMZ like any potential username and passwords cannot be applied to the internal LAN. Mind you this is a little more administration work but nothing that cannot be handled.

That is usually the logic of having a DMZ, if it is compromised then just delete and re-build it. So long as it protects the internal LAN which I believe will happen here.

Now that being said no system is 100% hack proof, if someone is determined enough then they will get in and wreck havoc.

The research goes on for best practices.

Thank you all for your feedback